# Conectar aplicativo android com messenger

Tags: android

Boa noite pessoal,

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo com caráter educacional, neste aplicativo que desenvolvo desejo criar um botão que abra o messenger para o usuário enviar uma pergunta a uma determinada página (onde tenho um bot para responder), mas estou perdido para começar, já li um pouco a documentação do próprio android e nao entendi muito bem. Se alguém puder me ajudar?